# Asp.net core Cleanest way to return View or Json/XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

In asp.net core I would like to set up my API controller to do the following:

by default `return View(model);`

/api/id.json to `return model;` as json

/api/id.xml to `return model;` as xml

The second two can be achieved by using the `[FormatFilter]` [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

```
[FormatFilter]
public class ProductsController
{
    [Route("[controller]/[action]/{id}.{format?}")]
    public Product GetById(int id)
```

However this requires the method to return an object and not a View(object). Is there anyway to cleanly support also returning Views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be using this pattern a lot, to keep your controllers as clean as possible, you could create a base class that exposed a "FormatOrView" method:

```
[FormatFilter]
public abstract class FormatController : Controller
{
  protected ActionResult FormatOrView(object model)
  {
    var filter = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<FormatFilter>();
    if (filter.GetFormat(ControllerContext) == null)
    {
      return View(model);
    }
    else
    {
      return new ObjectResult(model);
    }
  }
}
```

And then your controller can inherit from this and use the FormatOrView method

```
public class ProductsController : FormatController
{
  [Route("[controller]/[action]/{id}.{format?}")]
  public ActionResult GetById(int id)
  {
    var product = new { Id = id };

    return FormatOrView(product);
  }
}
```

Edit to list final accepted answer by GreyCloud: Here is a generic slightly simplified method you can put into a controller (or make an extension method or put into an abstract base class as above). Note the ?. in case the service is not defined for some reason.

```
private ActionResult<T> FormatOrView<T>(T model) {
     return HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<FormatFilter>()?.GetFormat(ControllerContext) == null 
          ? View(model) 
          : new ActionResult<T>(model);
```

}

Comment: Is there an easier way to make this work with the accept request header other than doing a string search in the FormatOrView method that checks for \*/\*, text/html, text/plain? FormatFilter.GetFormat only appears to be populated when an extension is applied

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do both in the same action. However, you can factor out the common functionality into a private method and then implement two actions with minimal code duplication:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[FormatFilter]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    private Product GetByIdCore(int id)
    {
        // common code here, return product
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]/{id}")]
    [ActionName("GetById")]
    public IActionResult GetByIdView(int id) => View(GetByIdCore(id));

    [HttpGet("[action]/{id}.{format}")]
    public Product GetById(int id) => GetByIdCore(id);
}
```

It's necessary to use different action names here, because the method signatures cannot differ merely on return type. However, the `[ActionName]` attribute can be used as above to make them appear to have the same name for the purposes of URL generation and such.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually achieve this just using the one action. Here's an example of how I got it to work:

```
[FormatFilter]
public class ProductsController : Controller
{
    [Route("[controller]/[action]/{id}.{format?}")]
    public IActionResult GetById(int id, string format)
    {
        var yourModel = ...;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(format))
            return View(yourModel);

        return Ok(yourModel);
    }
```

By using `IActionResult` as the return type, you can return either a `ViewResult` or an `OkObjectResult`. You can get access to the `format` value by taking it as a parameter in your action, check if it's empty and then react accordingly.

I also added `Controller` as the base class in order to access the convenience methods for creating the relevant results (`View(...)` and `Ok(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

The FormatFilter is part of the content negotiation of your app, in AspNetCore, you have the control to handle your input or output formatters also on the ConfigureServices where you have more control, even you can add more media types there

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvc(options =>
                {
                    options .OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
                    options .InputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerInputFormatter(options ));

                    //more output formatters
                    var jsonOutputFormatter = options.OutputFormatters.OfType<JsonOutputFormatter>().FirstOrDefault();

                    if (jsonOutputFormatter != null)
                    {

   jsonOutputFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add("application/vnd.myvendormediatype");                 

                    }
                }
}
```

But going back on the content negotiation in your controllers you can keep just one. The only thing is that you need to know the mediaType to return your View or your json content. Only be sure to pass an accept header with the content type you want. With the content type you are defining for an api or for an mvc application which is the content/format the client should expect

```
 [HttpGet("[action]/{id}")]
 public IActionResult public Product GetById(int id, [FromHeader(Name = "Accept")] string mediaType)
        {
           if (mediaType == "application/vnd.myvendormediatype")
           {
                 var data = GetYourData(...)
                 return Json(data);
           }
           else return View("YourDefaultView");
        }
```

Comment: this would work but it places a heavy burden on the consumers of the API

Comment: anyone that is consuming the api should know the content negotiation that you are exposing. You can document your api with swagger if you want, but at the end is a contract between the server and the client(the producer/consumer). Think about on your approach as well, you are forcing them to pass a format parameter to do your distinction in the backend